# FileReader manipulation for java

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter

I am trying to manipulate a java reader to break up pieces of a file into different strings.

Right now my writer will save multiple user input as information into a file such as a first name, last name, date of birth, and email.  Each part of information stored has a maximum number of characters that is allowed to be entered.

Example:

```
??????John???????Doe01012016???????john.doe@yahoo.com
```

If the first name is less than 10 characters, the unused characters are filled with "?" and so on for the other values.

How can I make the reader understand a string similar to the example and save the values so that I can later set them to an object?

```
public void reader() {

        String fileName = "C:/Users/johnDoe/Desktop/accounts.txt";

        String line = null;
        String fileContent = "";

        try {
            FileReader in = new FileReader(fileName);

            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(in);

            while((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                fileContent = fileContent + line;
            }   

            bufferReader.close();

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //used just to verify that the end result of the string fileContent is equal to the saved file.
        System.out.println(fileContent);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use String split.

```
String[] parts = myString.split("?");

for (String part : parts) {
    if (part.length() > 0) {
        *(do stuff)*
    }
}
```